# JavaScript beginner needs help if/then/else

Tags: javascript

I need a javascript that reads the QR code, if the URL or instruction shown matches the URL we use, it executes that script

If not, it pops up a warning that the code link is not one of ours, and offers a button to let the user launch the QR link.

Yes, this is a mobile app for my company to check inventory

Here's what I have

```
if (data.text == 'http://gmail.com') {
    window.open(data.text, '_system', 'location=yes'); 
}
else
{
    window.location = 'http://www.jths.co.uk/index.phtml?d=541300';
}
```

the only part that works (if I remove the rest of it) is this

```
window.open(data.text, '_system', 'location=yes');
```

Comment: So what exactly doesnt work? The comparison?

Comment: if data happens to be `undefined`, or not an object, that code will break. Try `if (data && data.text == 'http://gmail.com')` (which adds the condition that `data` does exist to the `if`) to at least check if the problem is related with that.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that "data" is undefined or not an object as Sergeon mentioned.

To investigate the issue, you could open browser's Developer Tools, check the console to see if it had any exceptions. You could also put the breakpoint to the line of:

```
if (data.text == 'http://gmail.com') {
```

Then you could watch the value of data and data.text or step over.